# Vuex/Electron: cannot import vuex-electron

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, electron, vuex

I want to use the plugins `createPersistedState` and `createSharedMutations` from `vuex-electron`.
I have installed it via npm i vuex-electron and noticed that its build failed on [Github](https://github.com/vue-electron/vuex-electron). I installed the version 1.0.0 of it which I use in another project (where it's working) but I can't import it in the store file.

I don't understand why its not working in the current project. Any idea?

Store snippet of current project

```
import { createPersistedState, createSharedMutations } from 'vuex-electron'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules,
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState,
    createSharedMutations
  ],
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
});
```

Error essage

```
5:61 Could not find a declaration file for module 'vuex-electron'. 'C:/Users/pasca/Projects/time-manager/node_modules/vuex-electron/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/vuex-electron` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vuex-electron';`
```

Comment: Did you try `npm install @types/vuex-electron`?

Comment: When i run this command, I am getting an error that it cant be found